# How do you use the clone feature in gremlin javascript?

Tags: javascript, gremlin

Trying to save and reuse a query- clone();

I have already tried `query.clone()`, `clone(query)`, `statics.clone(query)`, `graphPredicate.clone(query)`

reference: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#traversal-component-reuse

````
const { Graph } = gremlin.structure;
const { P: graphPredicate, statics } = gremlin.process;
const { _ } = gremlin.process.statics;

  const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(gremlinConnection);


const query = statics.hasLabel(‘Movie’).hasId(gt(‘C’))

const count = g.V().flatMap(query.clone()).count().next()```

`Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined`
````

Comment: Can you just declare query? Const query for example.

Comment: Replace statics with the gremlin.process.static alias. Also not really sure if you should use curly brackets. Try it.

Comment: @elanochecer We tried both of those things. At this point we thing that the problem is with the anonymous query. Have you done one before in JS?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `clone()` in javascript. But you can easily create one:

```js
function clone(traversal) {
  return new gremlin.process.GraphTraversal(
    traversal.graph,
    traversal.traversalStrategies,
    new gremlin.process.Bytecode(traversal.bytecode)
  )
}
```

you can also add it to the traversal itself: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-javascript-dsl

```js
class MyTraversal extends gremlin.process.GraphTraversal {
  constructor(graph, traversalStrategies, bytecode) {
    super(graph, traversalStrategies, bytecode)
  }

  clone() {
    return new MyTraversal(
      this.graph,
      this.traversalStrategies,
      new gremlin.process.Bytecode(this.bytecode)
    )
  }
}

class MyTraversalSource extends gremlin.process.GraphTraversalSource {
  constructor(graph, strategies, bytecode) {
    super(graph, strategies, bytecode, MyTraversalSource, MyTraversal)
  }
}

const g = traversal(MyTraversalSource).withRemote(dc)
```